# Why scipy.stats.chi2_contingency computes incorrect Pearson's chi-squared statistic?

Tags: statistics, independence, hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, chi-squared

I computed Pearson's chi-squared statistics for the contingency table bellow.

[image: observed]

Here are the expected values.

[image: expected]

**Method 1 (using SciKit)**

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
from scipy.stats import chi2

table = [[21,2], [14, 0]]
stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(table)
print(stat)
```

Returns

```
0.14814773735581194
```

**Method 2 (directly)**

```
G3 = 35*23/37
H3 = 2*23/37
G4 = 35*14/37
H4 = 2*14/37
(21-G3)**2/G3+(2-H3)**2/H3+(14-G4)**2/G4+(0-H4)**2/H4
```

Returns

```
1.2869565217391306
```

I expected the returned values to be equal. Why do they differ?

Comment: Read [the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html).  The default `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(observed, correction=True, lambda_=None)` is to apply [Yates's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity).

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you, you are right. If you wish, make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/) isn't the same library as [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html) (`sklearn`).

Answer (score 1):

There are many slightly different implementations of chi-squared tests within and among various kinds of software?

Here are four tests in R, using your table:

```
TBL = matrix(c(21,2,14,0), byrow=T, nrow=2)
TBL
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   21    2
 [2,]   14    0
```

Default chi-squared test in R, using Yates' continuity
correction. It gives an error message because counts
in some cells are too small for the chi-squared statistic
to have approximately a chi-squared distribution.

```
 chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

 data:  TBL
 X-squared = 0.14815, df = 1, p-value = 0.7003

 Warning message:
 In chisq.test(TBL) : 
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)
```

Without the continuity correction: Another error message
because of low counts.

```
        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 1.287, df = 1, p-value = 0.2566

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL, cor = F) : 
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Simulation to give a more reliable P-value:

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL
X-squared = 1.287, df = NA, p-value = 0.5042
```

Fisher exact test uses a hypergeometric distribution:

```
fisher.test(TBL)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.5165
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.000000 8.792391
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
     0
```

None of the tests gives a P-value significant at the 5% level.
With only two subjects in 'Senzitvne` outcome, you have
no chance for a significant between groups.